# When using inches, can you change how much dimensions panel steps?

Tags: interface, customization

I've set up my blend file to use inches for length, but noticed that in the Transform panel the steps are still stepping 100cm at a time. Is it possible to change this behavior?

[image: Stepping up units in Blender.]

Answer (score 0):

Change Unit Scale to 0.0254 since 1" = 0.0254 m.

[image: Unit Scale : 0.0254]

[image: Stepping increase/decrease by 0.1"]

You can learn more in [Scene Properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/scene/properties.html)

Comment: Changing dimensions as OP did does not change the real size of objects. Changing Unit Scale as you suggest does change the real size of objects.